# HTML video audio working but video is blank

Tags: php, html

Im trying to view a video with html but it doesnt work. The audio plays but the video stays blank. The video is an mp4 https://videos.laxnode.net/uploads/5qco8ocZli/4-Legged-Spoungebob-1.mp4. it works if you download it and view it though (dont question it, friend made it). I uploaded it to youtube and downloaded it again and it worked then to maybe its something with codec? if it is how could I fix it?

html

```html
<video width="960" height="620" controls>
        <source src=<?=$videofile?> type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss quote after `src=`

Its should be:

```
<video width="960" height="620" controls>
        <source src="<?=$videofile?>" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Change your tag with w3schools video:

```
<video width="960" height="620" controls>
            <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Your video is also corrupt.
Solution is: Convert with some mp4 converter.

Yes, i saw your red spongebob with 4 leg in paint :D

Comment: is there any good mp4 converters I can use? Would like it to happen when a video is uploaded.
Also cant take credit for the spongebob video :( friend made it

Answer (score 3):

If you convert your file to H.264 this will work, use this converter: https://www.ofoct.com/video-converter/convert-to-h-264-video.html

I've just tested it and the video plays.

Comment: Ended up using ffmpeg for converting in php. thanks though

Answer (score 1):

It seems your video file is corrupt, have you tried a converter?

Comment: I am going to use a converter, not sure if its corrupt because it works locally. Ive got ffmpeg working and it fixed the issue